# How can I change my script to output ul rather than select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the JS Fiddle I am referencing:

http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wKbXx/1/

What I would like to ultimately do is modify this to create an array of items associated with a parent category that is dynamically generated.  So…  for this example, if a user selects:

```
<li class="list"><input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Kitchen"/> Kitchen</li>
```

Then they would get a list of items associated with the Kitchen in a list:

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Cup</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Spoon</a></li>    
 <li><a href="#">Wine</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Salsa</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Oven</a></li>     
 </ul>
```

In the JS Fiddle it looks like I am headed in the right direction with the dynamic population of elements upon a user click, but it turns it into a select dropdown.  Any suggestion on how I can make this happen?  FYI, the associated items will be pulled from a database array.

Comment: Look in to jquery ui selectable http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

Comment: That is a good reference, but I am looking to be able to modify the output from a dropdown list to a `ul` as shown in JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `select` to `ul` is what you're trying to achieve.  I tried to simplify and make it to look consistent like add/remove the exact element based on the `checkbox`.

```
$('input[name=q1]').on('change', function () {
    var valu = this.value;
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#q2').append("<li>" + valu + "</li>");
        $('#question2').show();
    } else {
        var lis = $("#q2").find('li');
        lis.each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === valu) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        if (lis.length === 0) {
            $('#question2').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRc9W/1/)

Comment: @Presto, Praveen here has showed you the way to add `<ul>` instead of `<select>`. Now you 'll have to modify a little bit the code and display the list of items you want according to the parent category that was pressed.

Comment: @antithesis you are correct in the  next step.  If you would like to have a go at explaining how I can do this it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Presto I am little confused on your second step!??! can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are generating `<option>` elements and appending them to a `<select>`. This will create a drop-down menu.

If you want it to output a list with checkboxes... then you just need to change the HTML that you are inserting in the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/wKbXx/5/
Here I changed it so that instead of a `<select>` under question 2, there is a `<ul>`, and the jquery code generates and inserts `<li>` elements dynamically as you select items in question 1. Is this what you want? Compare this to your original code and you'll see it's basically the same, but with `<li>` instead of `<option>`.

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/wKbXx/6/
Here is a version with a radio button selection instead of checkbox selection.